# Postgres query: no results or too many results

Tags: postgresql

I need to search for addresses in a database, for example: Speicherstrasse 1.

If i use this query:

```
let sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM mainAddresses WHERE lokalisationsname ILIKE $1 AND hausnummer ILIKE $2";
```

it returns all results for house numbers that include 1: 10,11,21,61 etc.

If I use this query:

```
let sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM mainAddresses WHERE lokalisationsname = $1 AND hausnummer = $2";
```

it does not return anything.

This query for mysql was working perfectly, only returned the exact address, but I had to move to postgres:

```
let sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM mainAddresses WHERE lokalisationsname LIKE ? AND hausnummer LIKE ?";
```

What should be the query then for postgres?

Comment: LIKE, ILIKE and = are three different operators that could result in three different results even when the data is the same. And for both LIKE and ILIKE the content is also important, what wildcards did you use? And then the data, could you share some examples?